# How to use laravel's can() on routes when using JetStream

Tags: laravel, laravel-jetstream

I'm trying to work out how to use `->can()` on a route when combined with JetStream's permissions.

I can see how to create permissions in the `JetStreamServiceProvider.php`:

```php
 protected function configurePermissions()
    {
        Jetstream::defaultApiTokenPermissions(['read']);

        Jetstream::role('admin', __('Administrator'), [
            'export:orders'
        ])->description(__('Administrator users can perform any action.'));
```

However I can work out how to combine this with a route:

```php
Route::get('/generate-export/orders', [OrderExportController::class,'show'])->name('exportOrders.show')->can(' -- not sure what to put here --');
```

I've tried a few things and got nowhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those tokens are used for requests authenticated with sanctum. As their documentation states in:

[Sanctum 9.x - Token Ability Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sanctum#token-ability-middleware)

Yoiu need to first add 2 entries to the route middleware array in your `App\Http\Kernel.php` file.

```php
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    ...,
    'abilities' => \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\CheckAbilities::class,
    'ability' => \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\CheckForAnyAbility::class,
];
```

And then, you can use those middlewares in your routes.

```php
Route::get('/generate-export/orders', [OrderExportController::class,'show'])
    ->name('exportOrders.show')
    ->middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'ability:export:orders']); // check if user has export:orders ability
```

As for the difference between  `abilities` and `ability`, to quote the documentation:

> The `abilities` middleware may be assigned to a route to verify that the incoming request's token has all of the listed abilities:
>
> ```php
> Route::get('/orders', function () {
>     // Token has both "check-status" and "place-orders" abilities...
> })->middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'abilities:check-status,place-orders']);
> ```
>
> The `ability` middleware may be assigned to a route to verify that the incoming request's token has at least one of the listed abilities:
>
> ```php
> Route::get('/orders', function () {
>     // Token has the "check-status" or "place-orders" ability...
> })->middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'ability:check-status,place-orders']);
> ```

Comment: Of course - I should have considered this uses Sanctum. That's the part I was missing. Thank you.